# How can I fill the polygon when I click it?

Tags: vb.net

I set 5 line shapes to make a polygon. What I want to do is, if I click on the polygon, it becomes filled with a color. What should I do to make this possible?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read through the [help center](http://stackoverflow.com/help), in particular how to ask. Your best bet here is to do your research, search for related topics on SO, and give it a go. After doing more research and searching, post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) of your attempt and say specifically where you're stuck, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: There are as many ways to do this as there are programmers in the world. Make an attempt yourself first, and post back here with the code if you have trouble.

Comment: See: [GraphicsPath.AddPolygon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.drawing2d.graphicspath.addpolygon) and [Graphics.DrawPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.drawpath?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_Drawing_Graphics_DrawPath_System_Drawing_Pen_System_Drawing_Drawing2D_GraphicsPath_) + [Graphics.FillPath](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.graphics.fillpath?view=netframework-4.7.2)

Comment: I'm just trying another method because I had a problem in my main method. Please help me with this. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52505087/how-can-i-able-to-see-the-image-in-my-picturebox)